# jest unit test case for fetch call react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

// my unit test case for fetch call. i am trying to mock the fetch call. at that time i am checking whether the state updating or not. how can i do that

```
it('button press fetch data from json placeholder', async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn(
      () =>
        new Promise(resolve =>
          resolve({
            ok: true,
            json: () => Promise.resolve([1]),
          }),
        ),
    );

    const button = wrapper.find('[testID="inputButton"]');
    button.props().onPress();
    wrapper.update();
    console.log(wrapper.instance());
    expect(wrapper.instance().state.responseData.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

// Error

```
Expected: 1
Received: 0

  44 |     wrapper.update();
  45 |     console.log(wrapper.instance());
> 46 |     expect(wrapper.instance().state.responseData.length).toBe(1);
     |                                                          ^
  47 |   });
  48 | });
```

// Actual code in component

```
buttonPress = () => {
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      responseData: response,
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resolving the promise like this:

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() => new Promise.resolve({ok: true, json: <resolved value>})
```

You generally want to resolve all your promises by doing:

```
return expect(Promise).resolves/rejects.<assertion>
```

or by awaiting the result.

Comment: `buttonPress = () => {
     fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
         this.setState({
             responseData: response,
         });
      });
   }`

can you give me exact code for this buttonPress method

Comment: this dude explained it really well to me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo0psyTxgQM

Answer (score 0):

// after applying setTimeout() i can able the expect the updated state value

```
it('button press fetch data from json placeholder', async done => {
global.fetch = jest.fn(
  () =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      resolve({
        ok: true,
        json: () => Promise.resolve([1, 2]),
      }),
    ),
);

const button = wrapper.find('[testID="inputButton"]');
button.props().onPress();
wrapper.update();
setTimeout(() => {
  expect(wrapper.instance().state.responseData.length).toBe(2);
  done();
  });
});
```